# Customer Login Pages on Shopify always redirect to home page

Tags: e-commerce, shopify, liquid

I've been trying to go the Customer login page of my Shopify website. But it always redirect me to the shop homepage. It also happens the same thing for other customer  related pages. I can't understand why this happens. Here is my Shop URL.

https://baseonesolutions-jwellery-demo.myshopify.com/account/login/

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: where is your Login page? https://baseonesolutions-jwellery-demo.myshopify.com/pages/sign-in this one?

Comment: No, It is on them menu bar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please check again your Checkout setting. Select the second or third option of **Customer Account** section.

[image]